# Должна ли быть двухсторонняя ip связь Контроллера домена и клиента?

Tags: windows, сервер, dns, active-directory

Между офисами поднят IPSEC VPN. За клиентским VPN есть сеть, которая видит локальную сеть за сервером VPN. С клиентской сети резолвится в прямую и обратную сам DC и все компы из DNS записей. Но контроллер домена ничего про ip сеть за клиентом VPN не знает.

Правильно ли это?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ: 
Нет, неправильно! должна быть IP связность в обе стороны. В ином случае, те компы которые были в домене выпадут из доверия, завести по новой не получится по разным неизвестным ошибкам. Если кто подкинет где про это почитать, буду признателен.